# node.js and express file uploader

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am following this tutorial: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/uploading-files-made-fun/

I have followed the steps all the way up to where they create the routes and haven't actually created any views. It says

> Thats it we are all done with our server. Restart your server and
>   navigate to    `http://localhost:3000/upload`. You should see a JSON
>   response with the empty array of files.

However when I try to run app.js it sits for a few seconds and then just goes back to the command prompt. No errors are given and I am clueless as to how to fix this.

Here is my code in routes/uploadManager.js

```
var options = {
tmpDir:  __dirname + '/../public/uploaded/tmp',
uploadDir: __dirname + '/../public/uploaded/files',
uploadUrl:  '/uploaded/files/',
maxPostSize: 11000000000, // 11 GB
minFileSize:  1,
maxFileSize:  10000000000, // 10 GB
acceptFileTypes:  /.+/i,
// Files not matched by this regular expression force a download dialog,
// to prevent executing any scripts in the context of the service domain:
inlineFileTypes:  /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/i,
imageTypes:  /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/i,
imageVersions: {
    width:  80,
    height: 80
},
accessControl: {
    allowOrigin: '*',
    allowMethods: 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
    allowHeaders: 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition'
},
storage : {
    type : 'local'
}
};

var uploader = require('blueimp-file-upload-expressjs')(options);

module.exports = function (router) {
router.get('/upload', function (req, res) {
    uploader.get(req, res, function (obj) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
});

router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    uploader.post(req, res, function (obj) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
});

router.delete('/uploaded/files/:name', function (req, res) {
    uploader.delete(req, res, function (obj) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
});
return router;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. I was trying to run `node app.js` when I was supposed to be running `node bin/www` since this is an express.js app.

Comment: If you are using slush-express module to scaffold your app, you can run it using `gulp` command as well. This is same as `nodemon bin/www`